# Multiple server names in a single connection string

Tags: postgresql, connection-string, npgsql

In the PostgreSQL documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html, it has been said that multiple hosts can be specified in a single connection string such that all the hosts will be tried in order one after the other until one of the server gets succeeds.

But when i tried to implement the same setting in the  tag present in my ASP.net web.config file, it is throwing error as no such host name. I am using NpgSQL provider in order to connect to PostgreSQL database.

I need to add multiple server names in the connection string such that if the server#1 fails then it should try for the next server server#2 immediately provided in the order until it succeeds

Can you please suggest on how multiple hosts can be provided in the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

The Npgsql driver does not currently support this functionality. The issue tracking this is https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/732, I'm still hoping we can get this into the next release but there's a lot going on.

Answer (score 0):

Load balancing and failover is avaialble in Npgsql version 6. At the time of writing v.6 is in preview.

Simple failover example (server2 is only used if a connection could not be established to server1):

```
Host=server1,server2;Username=test;Password=test
```

Example with load balancing (round robin I guess):

```
Host=server1,server2,server3,server4,server5;Username=test;Password=test;Load
Balance Hosts=true;Target Session Attributes=prefer-standby
```

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/failover-and-load-balancing.html